# Sparking animation for Button

Tags: javascript, css, event-handling, animation

I just came through a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/frogermcs/LikeAnimation), which has an amazing animation for `Button` in Android.

So, I thought why not make that for web buttons too.

And I started designed that.

Here is my [**repo**](https://github.com/Zlytherin/SparkingButton) for the same.

Here is my **code:**

```js
let icons = $('.magic')

for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; ++i) {
    icons[i].onclick = function (element) {
        icons[i].classList.toggle('enabled');
    }
}
```

```css
.magic {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 50px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .magic i {
    color: orange;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    position: relative;
    animation: disable 0.5s forwards;
  }

  .enabled i {
    animation: enable 1s forwards;
  }

  .magic::before {
    content: "";
    top:calc(50% - 45px);
    left:calc(50% - 45px);
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    border-color: orange;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .enabled::before {
    transition:
      transform 0.5s,
      border-width 0.5s 0.2s;
    transform: scale(1);
    border-width: 0px;
  }

  .magic::after,
  .magic i::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 80px);
    left: calc(50% - 80px);
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
    background:
      radial-gradient(circle, red 50%, transparent 60%),
      radial-gradient(circle, red 50%, transparent 60%),
      radial-gradient(circle, red 50%, transparent 60%),
      radial-gradient(circle, red 50%, transparent 60%),
      radial-gradient(circle, orange 50%, transparent 60%),
      radial-gradient(circle, orange 50%, transparent 60%),
      radial-gradient(circle, orange 50%, transparent 60%),
      radial-gradient(circle, orange 50%, transparent 60%);

    background-position:  
      calc(50% - 50px) calc(50% - 50px),
      calc(50% - 50px) calc(50% + 50px),
      calc(50% + 50px) calc(50% - 50px),
      calc(50% + 50px) calc(50% + 50px),
      calc(50% - 0px) calc(50% - 70px),
      calc(50% - 70px) calc(50% - 0px),
      calc(50% - 0px) calc(50% + 70px),
      calc(50% + 70px) calc(50% - 0px);
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius:50%;
    transform: scale(0);
  }

  .magic i:after {
    background-size: 10px 10px;
    transform: rotate(10deg) scale(0);
  }

  .enabled::after {
    transition: 
      transform 0.5s 0.5s,
      opacity 0.4s 1s,
      background-size 0.4s 1s;

    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
    background-size: 0 0;
  }

  .enabled i:after {
    transition: 
      transform 0.5s 0.5s,
      opacity 0.4s 0.8s,
      background-size 0.4s 0.8s;

    transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1);
    opacity: 0;
    background-size: 0 0;
  }

  @keyframes enable {
    50% {
      filter: grayscale(100%);
      transform: scale(0);
    }
    51% {
      filter: grayscale(0%)
    }
    90% {
        transform: scale(1.3)
    }
    100% {
      filter: grayscale(0%);
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  }

  @keyframes disable {
      50% {
          filter: grayscale(0%);
          transform: scale(1.3);
      }
      100% {
          transform: scale(1);
      }

  }
```

```html
<span class="magic">
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-5x"></i>
</span>

<span class="magic">
    <i class="fas fa-bell fa-5x"></i>
</span>

<span class="magic">
    <i class="fas fa-bolt fa-5x"></i>
</span>

<span class="magic">
    <i class="fas fa-check fa-5x"></i>
</span>

<span class="magic">
    <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-5x"></i>
</span>

<!-- Other stuff -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
```

What do you reckon? Is there anything I can improve either in the *animation* or in the *code*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to suggest the opposite of Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ: Since you are using jQuery for selecting only, you can drop it altogether.

```
const icons = $(".magic");
```

becomes either

```
const icons = document.getElementsByClassName("magic");
```

or

```
const icons = document.querySelectorAll(".magic");
```

However you shouldn't use `on...` properties to assign event handlers. `on...` properties can only hold a single handler so if you or another script would attempt to assign another click handler then they'd overwrite each other. Instead use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Alternatively to avoid assigning seperate event handlers to each icon you could use event delegation. This means assign an single event handler to a surrounding element (or simply `document`) and check the target element:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("magic")) {
    event.target.classlist.toggle("enabled");
  }
};
```

Finally you could avoid using JavaScript altogether by using an HTML element that has the toggle functionality built in: a checkbox:

```
<label class="magic-wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox"><span class="magic"><i class="fas fa-star fa-5x"></i></span>
</label>
```

Hide the actual checkbox with:

```
.magic-wrapper > input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

(This is more accessable than just using display: none;)

And replace the selector `.enabled` with `input:checked + .magic` in the CSS.

Complete example: https://jsfiddle.net/rhy6gfn4/

---

A small points about the CSS:

You should select not just `.enabled` but use `.magic.enabled`, because then it's more obvious that these rules belong to the animated icons. Also "enabled" is a common class name and you don't want those styles apply to unrelated elements.

It would be a tiniest bit more performant to select the `i` elements using `.magic > i` and not just `.magic i`.

Answer (score 3):

Wow- that is some sparkly animations effects!

Because `icons` is only assigned one time, `const` can be used instead of `let`. This helps avoid accidental re-assignment.

If jQuery is going to be included on the page, then it can be used to simplify the JavaScript code - with the [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click) handler:

```
$('.magic').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('enabled');
});
```

That way there is no need to iterate over the collection of elements and add an `onclick` event handler to each one.